# Error in javascript embedded in HTML - Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, google-chrome, cors

I am doing a PoC. I have added the following javascript code in HTML page. This function get executed on button click but, it is not able to log response in console due to CORS issue.

```
function showText() {
  var a = "test";
  let btn = document.getElementById('desc');
  btn.innerHTML = a;

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  var url = 'https://json.freeastrologyapi.com/planets';
  let body = '{"year": 2001,"month": 10,"date": 26,"hours": 16,"minutes": 50,"seconds": 0,"latitude": 23.259933,"longitude": 77.412613,"timezone": 5.5,"settings": {"observation_point": "topocentric","ayanamsha": "lahiri"}}';

  xhr.open("POST", url);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      console.log(this.responseText);
    }
  }

  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("x-api-key", "API-TOKEN");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  xhr.send(body);
}
```

ERROR -

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://json.freeastrologyapi.com/planets' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

Comment: It is likely their API is not designed to be used from a browser client, otherwise they would have the correct CORS headers set. You will need to make the call from a server, or use one of the occasionally unreliable public CORS proxies. But remember, that second option will expose your API key to whoever has access to your website.

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` doesn't belong in a request. CORS is to be configured on the server side, not on the client side.

Comment: @jub0bs I was just trying, I just forgot to remove that line while posting.

Comment: @TonyB I was planning to create node server and then call API. Could you please explain the CORS proxies approach?